Is there a way to render HTML from a string in React without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or the React HTML Parser package?
I want to be able to send a HTML element as string in a prop to my component. I understand I can render this with dangerouslySetInnerHTML() but I don't want to set the "inner" HTML of anything - I just want to render the HTML element as it comes from the prop.
Eg if I send <a href="/somepage" data-attr="somthing">Link here</a> I just want to 'print' just that anchor tag element in my component.
dangerouslySetInnerHTML() could work but I'd have to wrap my sent element within another element.
Eg:
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: linkHtml }} />

Would render:
<div><a href="/somepage" data-attr="somthing">Link here</a></div>

The package React HTML Parser seems to do what I want but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it without using a third party package first.
Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this?

So you didn’t actually care whether it was a string, just that it could be passed in props?

@Ry- Part of the component I'm trying to recreate in React has a section that can be a link, or a button, or just a heading. Rather than create props for, say, the link name, the link url, any attributes, etc, I thought it would be better for the dev to just create an anchor tag or a button or p tag or whatever HTML they want that can then be passed as a prop and rendered in my larger component.

That’s very reasonable, but is that a “yes” then?

Yes I suppose so.

I think you can use this if you want use props:
<Mycomponent> 
    <div><a href="/somepage" data-attr="somthing">Link here</a></div>
</Mycomponent>

and in Mycomponent use:
interface MycomponentPropsType {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Mycomponent = ({ children }: MycomponentPropsType) => {
    return (
    <>
        {children}
    </>
    )
}

Another way that I think you don't want to use it is:
let node = `<div><a href="/somepage" data-attr="somthing">Link here</a></     div>`
let element = document.getElementById("Mycomponent")
element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", node)

